# github Залить собственною библиотеку без установки клиента

Tags: файлы, github

Я разработал полезную библиотеку для создания графического интерфейса С++ OpenGL теперь хочу поделиться ей, но не хочу чтобы кто то присвоил ее как автор. Принял риширение залить библиотеку сперва на github ат после уже на свой сайт. Но github очень неприятная штука как оказалось, залить просто файлы мне не удалось.

Вопрос в том как залить файлы но без установки клиента github.

Comment: Можно просто через командную строку залить. Нужно только `git` установить.

Comment: Контроль версий при разработке библиотеки чрезвычайно полезен. Так что польза от установки git или любого клиента для него не ограничится только возможностью загрузки на гитхаб.

Answer (score 1):

Если беспокоишься за свою интеллектульную собственность, можешь попробовать добавить в git репозиторий **лицензию**. Гит позволяет автоматически добавить ее, при создании репозитория. [Здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/243091/)  приводится детальное описание существующих лицензий, выбери ту, которая подходит, и вставь ее в репозиторий.

Comment: Лицензия предназначена не для защиты владельца интеллектуальной собственности, а для защиты её потребителей путём разрешения владельцем для них определённых, по умолчанию запрещённых авторским правом, действий (вроде распространения, изменения и многих способов использования). Да и к сути вопроса этот ответ не имеет никакого отношения.